# Downloading table data as CSV to local machine in Big query

Tags: python, google-bigquery

```
def downloadGbqToCsv(self,table_name,csv):

        credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    bigquery = discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

        job_data = {
        'sourceTable': {
                    'projectId': self.project_id,
                    'datasetId': self.dataset_id,
                    'tableId': table_name,
                },
                'destinationUris': 'path/to/download',
                'destinationFormat': 'CSV',
                'compression': 'NONE'
        }


        start = time.time()
        job_id = 'job_%d' % start
        # Create the job.

        result = bigquery.jobs().insert(projectId=self.project_id,body=job_data).execute()

        return result
```

How can I download the table data in CSV to my local machine?

Comment: OK, I'll ask the mandatory question: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i m try to upload a local csv file as table data in big query i have done that now what i need is to download the table data as csv to my local machine

Comment: For larger table, you will need to export to CloudStorage first, and download it to your local machine from there.

Answer (score 1):

Run an Extract Job to export your table to Google Cloud Storage in your desired format, then you can use any GCS tool to download the files to your local file system.

Here's an example extract job configuration: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery#extractconfig

I use `gsutil` to copy files from GCS to my local drive.

If you want to copy the table directly to your local drive, you will have to use [tabledata.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list) to list the table row-by-row, and convert it to your output format locally. The `bq` command `head` works this way, for ex:

> bq --format=csv head -n 100 project:dataset.table

But that only downloads the first 100 lines. The bq client doesn't support listing an entire table that way, as it's too slow. If your data sizes are small, however, it would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Executing a query and store in local machine is quite indirect in Big Query, I've packaged the code and hope it helps.

```
Packages version:
google-cloud (0.27.0)
google-cloud-bigquery (0.26.0)
google-cloud-storage (1.3.1)
```

https://github.com/IcarusSO/bigQueryExporter