# Is there any way to generate Microsft Excel from Bigquery result using Google appscript?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I want to export data from bigquery to ms excel using appscript as google spreadsheet has only 10 million cell limitation. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could export the table data into CSV (however, you could only export the data to Google Cloud Storage): https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

Then, you could download the data from GCS to your local machine. Here is a post about how that can be done: [Downloading table data as CSV to local machine in Big query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36257734/downloading-table-data-as-csv-to-local-machine-in-big-query)

Comment: CSV is not an option to me.. I simply need XLSX

Comment: Then, you could just open the CSV in Excel and save it as xlsx.

Comment: opening csv in excel changes data like '000445' to '45'. I know we can change it by changing the datatype but is there any automated version of that?